# Get last segment IP address

Tags: regex, bash, perl

In Bash can I get the last segment of an IP address by

```
$ A="10.10.10.46"
$ echo ${A##*.}
46
```

Can something similar easy be done in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get last octet by matching numbers to the end of the string,

```
my $A = "10.10.10.46";
print $1 if $A =~ /([0-9]+)$/;
```

or by splitting on dot char and selecting last list element,

```
my $num = ( split /[.]/, $A )[-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
my $a = "10.10.10.46";
print $1 if $a =~ /\.(\d{1,3})$/;
```

This regex will match the last 1 to 3 digits, and will make sure there's a dot in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

In perl use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

```
my $str1 = "10.10.10.46";
$out1 = substr($str1, -2);
```

Now suppose you have more than 2 digits;

To get everything after the last dot

```
(?<=\.)\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use this in `perl`:

```
my $A="10.10.10.46";
my @d = split(/\./, $A);
print $d[-1];
```

This will always print the last element based on `.` as separator. It does slice the string in pieces based on `.` and then prints the last element of the subsequent array.

Answer (score 0):

You want all the numbers at the end of the string, so ask for that.

```
($n) = $ip =~ /(\d+)$/;
```